# Trying to find a long R faq/quotation compilation

Tags: r

Some years ago I came across a large list of either questions and answers or compiled quotations (unfortunately I can't recall which) about the R language. It had been around for a while and I was surprised that I had never seen it before, at that point having already used R for many years

More importantly its tone was somewhat satirical, not really aimed at beginners, so I don't think it was a typical faq. The topics raised seemed to be pitched at the relatively experienced user.

All this is pretty vague but one of the quotes I recall was something like "everything clicked into place when I realized R was a lexically scoped language". Then there was some attempt at humour in the elaboration.

Any ideas what I'm talking about? It has proven difficult to Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [fortunes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/fortunes.pdf) library

> **Description** A collection of fortunes from the R community.

```
library(fortunes) 

fortune(6)

# It is good to look around at what is available, but one shouldn't miss
# what is under one's nose either.
# -- Robert Gentleman
# bioconductor (September 2003)
```